# n! modulo m , a^p modulo m

Tags: algorithm, math

Is there faster algo to calculate (n! modulo m). 
faster than reduction at every multiplication step.
And also
Is there faster algo to calculate (a^p modulo m) better than right-left binary method.

here is my code:
n! mod m

```
ans=1
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    ans=(ans*i)%m;
```

a^p mod m

```
result=1;
while(p>0){
    if(p%2!=0)
        result=(result*a)%m;
    p=(p>>1);
    a=(a*a)%m;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fast way to calculate n! mod m where m is prime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727962/fast-way-to-calculate-n-mod-m-where-m-is-prime)

Answer (score 1):

Now the `a^n mod m` is a `O(logn)`, It's the [Modular Exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) Algorithm.

Now for the other one, `n! mod m`, the algorithm you proposed is clearly `O(n)`, So obviously the first algorithm is faster.

Comment: are'nt there any number theory results which can make this better.

Comment: @user1131274, I tried an alternative method for calculating `n! mod m` but it wasn't much faster. I broke `n` into its prime factors `n =  p1^e1 p2^e2...pn^en` and then used `powMod` (first algorithm) to calculate `pi^ei mod m` and multiplied them together...There is probably a better method, but i don't know yet.

Comment: a^n mod m and n!mod m are fundamentally two different problems, I'm confused that you compared these two solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The standard trick for computing `a^p modulo m` is to use successive square. The idea is to expand `p` into binary, say

```
p = e0 * 2^0 + e1 * 2^1 + ... + en * 2^n
```

where `(e0,e1,...,en)` are binary (`0` or `1`) and `en = 1`. Then use laws of exponents to get the following expansion for `a^p`

```
a^p = a^( e0 * 2^0 + e1 * 2^1 + ... + en * 2^n )
    = a^(e0 * 2^0) * a^(e1 * 2^1) * ... * a^(en * 2^n)
    = (a^(2^0))^e0 * (a^(2^1))^e1 * ... * (a^(2^n))^en
```

Remember that each `ei` is either `0` or `1`, so these just tell you which numbers to take. So the only computations that you need are

```
a, a^2, a^4, a^8, ..., a^(2^n)
```

You can generate this sequence by squaring the previous term. Since you want to compute the answer `mod m`, you should do the modular arithmetic first. This means you want to compute the following

```
A0 = a mod m
Ai = (Ai)^2 mod m for i>1
```

The answer is then

```
a^p mod m = A0^e0 + A1^e1 + ... + An^en
```

Therefore the computation takes `log(p)` squares and calls to `mod m`.

I'm not certain whether or not there is an analog for factorials, but a good place to start looking would be at [Wilson's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem). Also, you should put in a test for `m <= n`, in which case `n! mod m = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

For the first computation, you should only bother with the mod operator if `ans > m`:

```
ans=1
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) {
    ans *= i;
    if (ans > m) ans %= m;
}
```

For the second computation, using `(p & 1) != 0` will probably be a lot faster than using `p%2!=0` (unless the compiler recognizes this special case and does it for you). Then the same comment applies about avoiding the `%` operator unless necessary.

Comment: While we are micro optimizing, `if(ans > m) ans -= m` will be faster.

Comment: @st0le but we're multiplying, so `ans` can be larger than `2m`.

Comment: @DanielFischer, doh! you're right and clearly `while(ans > m) ans-=m` will be slower aswell. So I respectfully retract my comment. :)

Comment: That would be `if(ans >= m) ...` Still, assuming `i! mod m` is fairly evenly distributed, the probability that the modulo operation is unnecessary is only about `1/i`. The branching may actually do more harm than good.

Comment: @JeffreySax - Yeah, I thought about that, but didn't analyze it. I figured that a subtract is really cheap compared to a mod. But maybe not that cheap.

Comment: hey guys is'nt there any number theory result which can be handy in above situations because i am dealing with real big numbers