# subfactorial modulo prime (!n mod p)

Tags: algorithm, math

Is there a simple way to implement `!n mod p` ([number of derangements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#Counting_derangements)) `where n ≤ 2∗10^8` and `p` is a prime and `p < 1000`

The program must execute fast so the naive approach doesn't work.

Comment: @SteveJessop is that the same as in the link?

Comment: @Luchian: yes, the subfactorial is the number of derangements.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - not apparently, that is what it means. I don't know why you reverted my edit... Obviously he doesn't want to calculate not n mod p. If you want just remove the c++ tag, it has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

You can read this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727962/fast-way-to-calculate-n-mod-m-where-m-is-prime

Comment: Out of curiousity, which SPOJ question would this happen to be?

Comment: @alestanis I'm looking for !n not for n!

Comment: Since `p < 1000`, it might be worth investigating if derangements are periodic mod `p`. For example, the first few `1, 0, 1, 2, 9, 44, 265, 1854, 14833, 133496, 1334961, 14684570, 176214841, 2290792932` are periodic mod `2` with a period of 2: odd even odd even ...; I'm pretty sure this holds forever and for other numbers too

Comment: `!n mod p` appears to be periodic with period `2p` (for odd p), so this gives a straightforward algorithm to compute the required value. You might want to try proving the periodicity though.

Comment: @Nabb It's on polish spoj http://pl.spoj.pl/problems/LETTERS5/

Comment: @BugMeNot I find there's this relation that works. `!n = floor(n!/e)`. Recursive factorial would take O(log N).

Comment: @zander: that formula is fine if you want a floating-point result but doesn't really help compute the value modulo `p` (you can't compute `floor(k/e) mod p` by knowing `k mod p`).

Comment: @zander it won't work since i have first divide within Real numbers, and therefore can't mod n! to reduce it. Mod is defined only for integers.

Comment: Yep, for p = 3 sequence is 1, 2 ,0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0; for p = 5 is 1, 0, 1, 2, 4, 4, 0, 4, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 4 ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out that `!n mod p` is periodic with a period of `2p`. Thus we can compute `!n mod p` as `!(n mod 2p) mod p`, which we do with the recursive formula for derangements `!n = (n-1) (!(n-1) + !(n-2))`.

For a proof:

- Observe that `!(p+1) = 0 mod p`, by the recursive relation for derangements.
- Working modulo p, `!(n+p) = !p * !n` (this can be proved inductively using the previous observation).
- Observe that `!p = -1 mod p`. Wikipedia provides a formula: `!n = n! - Sum[(n choose i) * !(n-i), i=1..n]` -- modulo p, the only nonzero term on the right hand side appears where `i=n`.
- Conclude that `!(n+2p) = !p !p !n = !n mod p`.

From the proof, we see that we can in fact compute `!n = ± !(n mod p) mod p` where the sign is positive when `n mod 2p` is less than `p`.

Answer (score 0):

Having the recursive formula (`!n = (n - 1) (!(n-1) + !(n-2))`), why not implement the operations "multiplication modulo `p`" and "addition modulo `p`"?

Comment: For `n` that large? Way too slow.

Comment: @Vlad: too slow I'd think, since it might require approx 400M operations.

Comment: execute time is around 0,2s n multiplications would take way too long. I believe that there's some clever way to reduce problem, because p limit is p < 1000.

Comment: @BugMeNot - that's a pretty important restriction! Please add it to the OP, together with any other information.

Comment: On consideration though this relation is probably a valid way forward. If you memoize the function `f(a,b,c) { return (a-1)(b + c) % p}`, then you need at worst a billion values given `p < 1000`. But Nabb observes above that `!n mod p` appears to be cyclic with shorter period than that, so actually you need rather fewer. Throw in some cycle-detection too, and you can probably get the value quite quickly. And that's without doing any maths -- *proving* some nice formula like `2*p` for the cycle length ahead of time would be preferable but probably not necessary given a 0.2s time constraint :-)

Comment: @Steve: Memoizing a function that does only 3 arithmetic operations? Really? ;)