# Divide and conquer method of factorial function using BigDecimal format returns stackoverflow error

Tags: java, math, stack-overflow, factorial

I have some code which I want to carry out a factorial function, however when I implemented a BigDecimal format into my code it seemed to run into a StackOverflow error.

P.S sorry if the question is not a proper question :)

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Factorial {
    public static BigDecimal TWO = new BigDecimal("2");
    public static BigDecimal ONE = new BigDecimal("1");

public static BigDecimal EvalFact(BigDecimal x, BigDecimal y ){
    return x.multiply(y);
}
public static BigDecimal factorial(BigDecimal m , BigDecimal n){
    BigDecimal z = m;
    if(!m.equals(n)){
        BigDecimal p = (n.subtract(m)).divide(TWO,0, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
        BigDecimal x = factorial(m, m.add(p));
        BigDecimal add_y = ONE.add(m.add(p));
        BigDecimal y = factorial(add_y, n);
        z = EvalFact(x, y);
    }
    return z;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    int k = 0;
    while(k == 0){
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter value for n: ");
    String sn = user_input.nextLine();

    BigDecimal n = new BigDecimal(sn);

    BigDecimal fact = factorial(ONE,n);

    String sfact = String.valueOf(fact);

    System.out.println(sfact);
    }


}

}
```

Comment: `if(m != n){` doesn't do what you want ;).

Comment: oh yeah thanks, silly me lol

Comment: How big a number are you having the user enter?  This is using recursion, so getting a stackoverflow is not totally unexpectable.

Comment: this [Fast exact bigint factorial](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18333853/2521214) might interest you