# How many zero total in 100 factorial

Tags: math

I have a homework that count total zero in n factorial. What should i do?
I only find way to  count trailing of factorial

```
static int findTrailingZeros(int n) 
{ 
    // Initialize result 
    int count = 0; 

    // Keep dividing n by powers  
    // of 5 and update count 
    for (int i = 5; n / i >= 1; i *= 5) 
        count += n / i; 

    return count; 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is not completely clear. Are you asking how to find the number of *all* zero digits in a factorial in base ten, including but not limited to the zero digits at the *end* of the factorial? Also, what is the range of possible values of `n` when examining `n!`?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an easy formula for this. See https://oeis.org/A027869 I don't see any straightforward way other than the brute force way of computing the number then counting the 0's. On the other hand, the trailing 0's problem is a classic puzzle and a common homework problem. Are you sure that you read the homework correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The total number of zeros in `n!` is given by sequence [A027869](https://oeis.org/A027869) in the On-line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences. There really seems to be no way to compute the total number of zeros in `n!` short of computing `n!` and counting the number of zeros. With a big int library, this is easy enough. A simple Python example:

```
import math

def zeros(n): return str(math.factorial(n)).count('0')
```

So, for example, `zeros(100)` evaluates to `30`. For larger `n` you might want to skip the relatively expensive conversion to a string and get the 0-count arithmetically by repeatedly dividing by `10`.

As you have noted, it is far easier to compute the number of trailing zeros. Your code, in Python, is essentially:

```
def trailing_zeros(n):
    count = 0
    p = 5
    while p <= n:
        count += n//p
        p *= 5
    return count
```

As a heuristic way to estimate the total number of zeros, you can first count the number of trailing zeros, subtract that from the number of digits in `n!`, subtract an additional 2 from this difference (since neither the first digit of `n!` nor the final digit before the trailing zeros are candidate positions for non-trailing zeros) and guess that 1/10 of these digits will in fact be zeros. You can use [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) to estimate the number of digits in `n!`:

```
def num_digits(n):
    #uses Striling's formula to estimate the number of digits in n!
    #this formula, known as, Kamenetsky's formula, gives the exact count below 5*10^7
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return math.ceil(math.log10(2*math.pi*n)/2 + n *(math.log10(n/math.e)))
```

Hence:

```
def est_zeros(n):
    #first compute the number of candidate postions for non-trailing zerpos:
    internal_digits = max(0,num_digits(n) - trailing_zeros(n) - 2)
    return trailing_zeros(n) + internal_digits//10
```

For example `est_zeros(100)` evaluates to 37, which isn't very good, but then there is no reason to think that this estimation is any better than asymptotic (though *proving* that it is asymptotically correct would be very difficult, I don't actually know if it is). For larger numbers it seems to give reasonable results. For example `zeros(10000) == 5803` and `est_zeros == 5814`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this then.

```
count = 0
s = str(fact)
for i in s:
    if i=="0":
        count +=1
print(count)
```

Comment: questioner's want number of zeros only in 100 factorial. 100! has 24 zeros in it. and code is giving output as 24.

Comment: @vishakhamote 100! has 30 zeros in it, though it has 24 *trailing* zeros. In any event, this code is just OP's code in Python so in no way constitutes an answer.

Comment: If you are going to use Python to brute-force it, just use `str(math.factorial(n)).count('0')` since the `count` method will be much quicker than the explicit loop. None of this really helps OP since they seem to want either a mathematical formula or Java code.

Answer (score 0):

**100! is a big number:**

```
100! = 93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000
```

To be more precise it need ~525 bit and can not be computed without some form of `bigint` math.

However **trailing zeros** might be computable on normal integers:

The idea is to limit the result to still fit into your data type. So after each iteration test if the result is divisible by 10. If it is increment your zeros counter and divide the result by 10 while you can. The same goes for any primes except  those that divide 10 so not: `2,5` (but without incrementing your zeros counter). This way you will have small sub-result and count of trailing zeros.

So if you do a `2,5` factorization of all the multiplicants in `n!` the min of the both exponents of 2,5 will be the number of trailing zeros as each pair produces one zero digit (`2*5 = 10`). If you realize that exponent of `5` is always smaller or equal than exponent of `2` its enough to do the factorization of `5` (just like you do in your updated code).

```cpp
int fact_trailing_zeros(int n)
    {
    int i,n5;
    for (n5=0,i=5;n>=i;i*=5) n5+=n/i;
    return n5;
    }
```

With results:

```
Trailing zeors of n!
       10! :         2
      100! :        24
     1000! :       249
    10000! :      2499
   100000! :     24999
  1000000! :    249998
 10000000! :   2499999
100000000! :  24999999
[   0.937 ms]
```

However `100!` contains also **non trailing zeros** and to compute those I see no other way than compute the real thing on a `bigint` math ... but that does not mean there is no workaround like for trailing zeros...

If it helps here are computed factorials up to `128!` so you can check your results:

- [Fast exact bigint factorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18333853/2521214)

In case `n` is bounded to small enough value you can use **LUT** holding all the factorials up to the limit as strings or **BCD** and just count the zeros from there... or even have just the final results as a **LUT** ...

Answer (score 0):

Here some bad code, but it works. You have to use TrailingZeros() only

```
    public static int TrailingZeros(int n)
    {
        var fac = Factorial(n);
        var num = SplitNumber(fac);
        Array.Reverse(num);
        int i = 0;
        int res = 0;

        while (num[i] == 0)
        {
            if (num[i] == 0)
            {
                res++;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return res;
    }
    public static BigInteger Factorial(int number)
    {
        BigInteger factorial = 1;   // значение факториала

        for (int i = 2; i <= number; i++) 
        {
            factorial = factorial * i;
        }
        return factorial;
    }

    
    public static int[] SplitNumber(BigInteger number)
    {
        var result = new int[0];
        int count = 0;

        while (number > 0)
        {
            Array.Resize(ref result, count + 1);
            result[count] = (int)(number % 10);
            number = number / 10;
            count++;
        }
        Array.Reverse(result);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: The code seems interesting, but commenting within the text would help to understand it. I suggest to remove the unnecessary indentation. The code contains russian comments: please keep them, but please translate into english.