# Find factorial n modulo m faster than O(n)

Tags: algorithm, math, factorial

How can I find `(n!) % m` **faster** than `O(n)`?

> 1 <= **n** <= 1e18
>
> 1 <= **m** <= 1e6

Comment: For small `m`, `m <= n`, `(n! mod m) == 0` that's why whenever `n >= 1e6` you can just return `0` and in the worst case you have `O(m)` time complexity

Comment: You can use any Fast Factorial algorithm like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18333853/2521214) ... you just use modlular arithmetics so no need for bigints so the resulting complexity will be somwhere between `O(log2(n))`  and `O(n)`  but much less than `O(n)` ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily have `O(m)` time complexity in the worst case (when `m` is a *prime*) and it seems to be good enough since you have `m <= 1e6` (while `n` can be up to `1e18`). Note, that when `n >= m`

```
 n! = 1 * 2 * ... * m * ... * n
                    ^
         factorial is divisible by m
```

and that's why

```
 n! % m == 0       # whenever n >= m
```

Another *implementation* detail is that you don't have to compute `n! % m` as `1 * 2 * ... * n % m` but you can do it as `((..(1 % m) * 2 % m) ... * n % m)` in order not to deal with huge numbers.

**C#** code example

```
private static int Compute(long n, long m) {
  if (n >= m)
    return 0;

  long result = 1;

  // result != 0 - we can well get 0 and stop looping when m is not prime 
  for (long d = 2; d <= n && result != 0; ++d) 
    result = (result * d) % m;

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Why do you say "when m is a prime"?

Comment: @Kelly Bundy:  When `m` is prime, then we can guarantee, that all factorials `1!, 2!, ... (m - 1)!` are *not divisible* by `m` (and we have to compute remainders). If m! is not a prime it can occure that starting from some `k!` (`k < m`) all the factorials are divisible by `m`. For instance: `m = 6` (not a prime) and we have `3! == 6` divisibe by `m = 6`. So starting from `3` (not from `m - 1 == 5`) all factorials are divisible by `6`

Comment: But it's still O(m).

Comment: @Kelly Bundy: yes, for arbitrary `m` we have `O(m)` time complexity; *prime* `m` is the worst case - we have to compute till `(m - 1)!`, if `m` is not prime we will stop earlier

Comment: Ah, ok. To me, the sentence reads as *"You can do it in O(m) if m is a prime [and if it's composite, it takes more time]"*.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by Dmitry, you can suppose than m<n. Let p1....pk the list of primes smaller or equal to m. Then m! mod n=(p1^a1.p2^a2....pk^ak)mod n=(p1^a1)mod n.(p2^a2 mod n)....(pk ^ak mod n) (mod n) for some a1.... ak that I'll let you find by yourself.

Using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation, you can then compute m! (mod n).