# What is the time complexity of math.factorial() function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, caching, time-complexity

Is there any way to reduce the time complexity of the factorial function below O(n), and what is the time complexity of its implementation in the math library in python?

Also, is any memoization done for some set of inputs (in Python 3), to further reduce its runtime?

Comment: There is no way to reduce the time complexity of the factorial function to below O(n), since n! has approximately n log n digits. That's assuming you're interested in wall time, and not the number of (big-int) arithmetic operations.

Comment: I don't believe there's memoization, but factorials of small numbers are precomputed: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d42f264f291e/Modules/mathmodule.c#l1396

Comment: see [Fast exact bigint factorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18333853/2521214) no You can not go under `O(n)` because fast factorials have big overhead so its meaningless to use them for CPU native datatypes and bigints introduce bigger complexity as most basic math operations are `O(m)` (where `m` is bitwidth of number) or worse ... For example the best I could do for `n!` is `~O(n^1.4)` However for CPU native datatype you can do `O(1)` LUT as only few factorials are possible to fit into 32 or 64 bit ints

Answer (score 4):

Python uses the divide-and-conquer method for computing factorials.

See if [this](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d42f264f291e/Modules/mathmodule.c#l1218) helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not mind floating point precision, `math.lgamma(n+1)` returns the natural logarithm of the factorial of n.

Comment: Do you also know the time complexity of this function?

Comment: On my computer can do about 5,000,000 calls a second, independent of the size of n, so time complexity is O(1).