# Why do these factorial algorithms differ so much in performance

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance, factorial

I have some questions about the following code

```
using UnityEngine;

    private void Calc(int n) {
        float time = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
        (int fact, int fact1, int fact2, int fact3) =(1,1,1,1);
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i+=4) {
            fact *= i;
            fact1 *= i+1;
            fact2 *= i+2;
            fact3 *= i+3;
        }
        time = Time.realtimeSinceStartup - time;
        Debug.Log("calc: "+time);
    }

    private void Calc_2(int n) {
        float time = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
        int fact = 1;
        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            fact *= i;
        }
        time = Time.realtimeSinceStartup - time;
        Debug.Log("calc_2: "+time);
    }
```

When n=2000000000, the calculation time of the two pieces of code is very different

```
calc: 0.4483032
calc_2: 1.34198
```

why is there such a big difference in performance between two similar pieces of code?

Comment: Try and make both output the factorial. How soon after initiating each multiplication is the product to be used as an input operand? How does an unrolled variant of `Calc_2()` perform?

Comment: Do both calculations have the same result though? In case they don't, the comparison is between apples and oranges.

Comment: I agree with @TheodorZoulias, those two functions don't compute the same thing. The last one would have to make a final multiplication of the 4 terms, and would need to do some adjustments when `n` is not a multiple of 4.

Comment: @AloisChristen You all missing the point of the question why it is faster ... which is related to CPU HW architecture. I added an answer with some explanation on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not coding in your environment so I might be wrong but modern CPUs can do **several independent instructions at the "same" time** (how many depends on how many **prefetch statges** there is inside **CPU** core)

if you unrol naive iteration:

```
for (fact=1,i = 2; i < n; i++) fact *= i;
```

you got:

```
...

i++;
if (i>=n) break;  // this is brunch which can mess things up but its true only once
fact *= i;        // here fact depends on the i from i++ before so it has to wait for its result

i++;
if (i>=n) break;
fact *= i;

i++;
if (i>=n) break;
fact *= i;

...
```

Now if you unrol your faster version:

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i+=4) {
            fact *= i;
            fact1 *= i+1;
            fact2 *= i+2;
            fact3 *= i+3;
        }
```

you (on good compiler) should got something like this:

```
...

i+=4;
if (i>=n) break;  // this is brunch which can mess things up but its true just once    
i1 = i+1;         // these depends on i+=4 from above so it must wait
i2 = i+2;         
i3 = i+3;
fact  *= i;       // these depends on i+1,i+2,i+3 above so it must wait
fact1 *= i1;
fact2 *= i2;
fact3 *= i3;

i+=4;
if (i>=n) break; 
i1 = i+1;
i2 = i+2;
i3 = i+3;
fact  *= i;
fact1 *= i1;
fact2 *= i2;
fact3 *= i3;

i+=4;
if (i>=n) break; 
i1 = i+1;
i2 = i+2;
i3 = i+3;
fact  *= i;
fact1 *= i1;
fact2 *= i2;
fact3 *= i3;

...
```

so still a lot of waits but when you look closer you wait for instructions that was executed in most cases 4 instructions before so they most likely already executed so they might not wait a at all and if your CPU core has at least 4 prefetch stages it might execute 4 iterations at once ... if you enlarge the number of executed instructions per iterations the performance will stop improving once you have more "paralel" computations than you have prefetch stages on your CPU.

Also the faster version has 4 times less brunches (as it has 4 times less loop iterations) which has also some minor impact on speed.

However once you change your factorial to **bigint** as `2000000000!` will not fit 32 nor 64 bit `int` this will no longer matter because even basic operations like `++,--,+,-,*,/` will no longer be just single instruction but entire program with its own complexity ...

For such high results you need to combine fast algorithms like these:

- [Fast exact bigint factorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18333853/2521214)
- [NTT based Schönhage-Strassen multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18577076/2521214)

or better...

Answer (score 0):

Your `calc` method iterates by 4 after each loop with `i+=4` whereas the `calc_2` method iterates 1 at a time with `i++`

So that means your `calc` method reaches `n=2000000000` approximately 4 times faster than your `calc_2` which is evident by your time results. In this case, the operations performed within each iteration is not too relevant considering how vastly different the number of loop iteration is between those two methods.

Comment: But if the loop body is irrelevant, then how is 4 times doing nothing any slower than doing it just once?

Comment: @thomas while I agree that the body is relevant, even with an empty body you'd go faster by iterating by 4 every loop. (Barring optimisation from the compiler ofc)

Comment: @Thomas Loops are a branching instruction. On average, modern processors happens to use in the range of 1 to 4 clock cycles per wrap. So even if this loop body contains nothing, there is still work being done by the processor.

Comment: To add to the previous comment, there are some compilers that can detect that the loop is doing no work and save some clock cycles there, but for the scope of this question, its important to know that there is a cost to iterating, so iterating a loop 4 at a time than 1 has a drastic effect to how fast it reaches n=2000000000