# Fast algorithm to calculate large n! mod 2³²

Tags: algorithm, biginteger, modulo, factorial

I want to calculate the exact value of N! mod 2<sup>32</sup>. N can be up to 2<sup>31</sup>

Any language is fine but I would appreciate detailed explanation of algorithm.
Time limit is < 1 sec

Comment: Is there a practical application to this problem? The number (2^31)! is kind of ridiculously huge. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384160/calculating-factorial-of-large-numbers-in-c for more discussion of this.

Comment: It's impossible for a (standard desktop) computer to even write down a number that large in less than a second.

Comment: @Andrew: It's about 4 billion, it's really not *that* huge..

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I'm talking about (2^32)! and not 2^32. The former containing over a billion digits.

Comment: @Andrew: When calculating `n! mod p` under normal circumstances *(ie. when `p` is prime)*, you always mod after each multiplication; then the numbers you deal with are never larger than `p`.  See my comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9728079/238419) for more info.

Answer (score 22):

In python:

```
if n > 33:
  return 0
else
  return reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, range(1, n+1)) % 2**32
```

Justification:

We know that 34! is divisible by 2<sup>32</sup> because in the sequence:

```
1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * ... * 34
```

there are:

```
17 multiples of 2
 8 multiples of 4
 4 multiples of 8
 2 multiples of 16
 1 multiple  of 32
--
32 multiplications by 2
```

It's a factor of every larger factorial, so all the larger ones are 0 mod 2<sup>32</sup>

For small values of N, if you don't have bignum arithmetic available, you can do the individual multiplications mod 2<sup>32</sup>, and/or you can prefactor the power of 2 in the factorial, which is easy to compute (see above).

Comment: the modulo 2**32 part is only needed because Python supports bigint math. In most normal languages you just need to do a direct multiplication on a 32-bit type and the result is already modulo 2³² automatically

Answer (score 6):

Calculate the factorial normally (multiply the numbers 1,2,3,...), performing the modulo after each multiplication. This will give you the result for small values of `N`.

For larger values of `N`, do the same. Pretty soon, your intermediate result will be `0`, and then you can stop the loop immediately and return `0`. The point at which you stop will be relatively fast: For `N == 64` the result will already be `0` because the product of `1..64` contains 32 even numbers and is therefore divisible by `2^32`. The actual minimal value of `N` where you get 0 will be less than 64.

Comment: *The actual minimal value of N where you get 0 will be < 64* 34, as [rici](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15230586/3789665) and [Joni](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15233896/3789665) stated on the same day, if later.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can implement algorithms modulo small powers of two without bignums or modular reduction using the integer types (int, long) available in most programming languages. For modulo 2<sup>32</sup> you would use a 32-bit int. ["Integer overflow" takes care of the modular arithmetic.](http://jonisalonen.com/2013/mathematical-foundations-of-computer-integers/)

In this case, since there are only 34 distinct results, a lookup table may be faster than computing the factorial, assuming the factorials are used often enough that the table gets loaded into the CPU cache. The execution time will be measured in microseconds.

Answer (score 0):

When multiplying 2 numbers of arbitrary length, the lower bits are **always exact** because it doesn't depend on high order bits. That's how 2-adic or p-adic multiplication works. Basically **a×b *mod* m = [(a *mod* m)×(b *mod* m)] *mod* m** so to do *N! mod m* just do

```
1×2×...×N mod m = (...(((1×2 mod m)×3 mod m)×4 mod m)...)×N mod m
```

Modulo 2<sup>n</sup> is a special case because getting the modulus is rather easy with an `AND` operation. Modulo 2<sup>32</sup> is even more special because all unsigned operations in C and most C-like languages are reduced modulo 2<sup>32</sup> for a 32-bit unsigned type

As a result you can just **multiply the numbers in a twice-as-wide type** then after that `AND` with 2<sup>32</sup> - 1 to get the modulus

```c
uint32_t p = 1;
for (uint64_t i = 1; i <= n && p /* early exit because product = 0 */; i++)
    p = uint32_t(p*i); // or p = p*i & 0xFFFFFFFFU;
return p;
```

Answer (score -1):

Calculating a modulo is a very fast operation, especially the modulo of a power of 2. A multiplication is very costly in comparison.

The fastest algorithm would factorize the factors of the factorial in prime numbers (which is very fast since the numbers are smaller than 33). And get the result by multiplying all of them together, by taking the modulo in between each multiplication, and starting with the big numbers.

E.g.: to calculate 10! mod 2<sup>32</sup>: use de Polignac's formula, to get the prime factors of 10!
which gives you :

> 10! = 7 * 5 * 5 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 2 ...

this would be faster than the basic algorithm, because calculating
(29! mod 2<sup>32</sup>) X 30
is much harder than multiplying by 5, 3 and 2, and taking the modulo in between each time.

Comment: This would actually be a lot slower. First there is a lot of extra work in doing the factorizing, and then a lot more multiplications. I don't know why you think that multiplying by 5, 3, and 2, performing a modulo each time, is faster than multiplying by 30.

Comment: Again, the numbers to factorize are very small, so easy so factorize. But the number to multiply are big, so hard. It's clear that if you can reduce the size of the intermediate result, you're gonna be faster. Try to calculate 67 * 4 mod 100. The best way is : 67 * 2 = 134, 34 * 2 = 68. By doing that I avoided multiplying 134 by 2.

Comment: A multiplication is not "an operation", as complexity theory tries to teach it. Yes this algorithm is doing more multiplications than the first one, but the complexity of each multiplication is much smaller.

Comment: @double_squeeze: actually you can leave out the factors of 2 altogether, as I mentioned in my answer. However, for `n < 34`, it's hardly worth it: I can compute the entire range in 32 milliseconds (including python startup) on my not-particularly fancy laptop.

Comment: Yes I agree, for this particular small example it is not really worth it. But let's say you don't have a computer available, and you need to do it by hand, you definitely want to do that.

Comment: @double_squeeze: if you were doing it by hand, you'd want to use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Polignac%27s_formula rather than trying to factor all those numbers one at a time, which would be seriously inefficient no matter how small they are.