# Modulus for factorial and divide

Tags: algorithm, modulus

How to solve `(a! / (b! * c!)) % mod`. Here `a!` is factorial of `a`.

Just as `(a + b) % mod = (a % mod + b % mod) % mod`

I know to calculate `(a * b) % mod`.

But how to take modulus of this type of function?

**UPDATED:** Whats the best way to find `(a / (b * c)) % mod`.
Here `mod` is prime number.

Comment: Please clarify. Your question is a bit confusing.

Comment: @KRUKUSA What you did not understand?

Comment: mod what? Is the modulus prime?

Answer (score -1):

Note that `(a! / (b! * c!)) % M` equals `((a! % M) / ((b! % M) * (c! % M))) % M` so implement `x! % M`:

```
def modfac(x, M):
    if x == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return (modfac(x-1, M)*x)%M
```

That could be made iterative but its only an example.

And then use it:

```
(modfac(a,M) / (modfac(b,M) * modfac(c,M))) % M
```

Comment: For computing n! mod M quickly, see [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727962/fast-way-to-calculate-n-mod-m-where-m-is-prime)

Comment: @DanD WHat if denomnator term overflow the range of integer?should we compute denominator modulo using inverse modulo or so?I mean question reduces now to (a/(b*c))%mod