# An optimized algorithm for the given problem?

Tags: c++, optimization

I am solving a problem which states that we have a list L containing integers from 1 to N. We have to perform the following operation N−1 times:

1. Choose two elements of the list, let's denote them by X and Y.
2. Erase the chosen elements from L.
3. Append the number X + Y + X*Y to L.
   At the end, L contains exactly one integer. Find this integer.
   As the answer may be large, we have to compute it modulo 10^9 + 7

Constraints : 
1≤N≤1,000,000

Time Limit : 
1 sec

I have written this code which gives the correct answer in linear time but it says time limit exceeded for this approach. Can someone provide a better optimized solution

```
inline ull cal(ull x, ull y){
  ull ans, i, modno;
  modno = 1000000007;
  i = 1;

  ans = (x + y);
  i = (i*x) % modno;
  i = (i*y) % modno;
  ans = ans + i;
  ans = ans % modno;
  return ans;
}

int main(){
    ull n;
    cin>>n;

    ull sum, modno;
    sum = 0;
    modno = 1000000007;

    if(n == 1)
        cout<<1<<endl;
    else
    {
        sum = n + (n-1) + (n*(n-1));
        n -= 2;
        do
        {
            if(n <= 0)
                break;

            sum = cal(sum, n);
            n -= 1;
        }while(1);
        cout<<ans<<endl;
     }

   return 0;
}
```

Final code :

```
    ull n;
    cin>>n;

    if(n == 1)
        cout<<1<<endl;
    else
    {
        ull modno = 1000000007;
        ull ans = 1;
        ull no = n+1;

        while(no >= 1)
        {
            ans = (ans*no);
            if(ans > modno)
                ans = ans%modno;
            no--;
        }

        ans = ans - 1;
        ans = ans % modno;
        cout<<ans<<endl;
```

Comment: consider what would be the solution if in 3) you would have to use just `X + Y`, then try to approach in small steps (eg what would be the solution for `X + Y + c` for some constant `c`?)

Comment: Performance increase function are more suited for "http://codereview.stackexchange.com".

Comment: The question being asked about is [REDONE](https://www.codechef.com/MAY19B/problems/REDONE), in case anyone is remotely curious about conditions left out by the OP's description.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Please Help Me Solve this Competitive Programming Problem in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56000228/please-help-me-solve-this-competitive-programming-problem-in-c?rq=1)

Comment: The final code added also gives time limit exceeded. Can someone please provide an efficient implementation for the problem? I have also tried fast factorial algorithms like Wilson's theorem.. Maybe it needs a different approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the problem boils down to calculating ((n + 1)! - 1) % p. You can search around about fast methods of doing this (fast factorial modulo prime). One of those that would work under 1s is the one mentioned [here](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/63491)

**Update**: Just checked the problem link from codechef. As usual, the trick lies in the constraints which you haven´t accurately described. You have to do the same task for up to 100000 cases. A single fact(n) mod p can be obtained in under 1 second using standard for loop, as n is small.

What won´t work is calculate fact(n) mod p for every test case. Like many other problems, you can benefit using precomputation: build an array where arr[i] is i! mod p up to i = max value n can take + 1. With this information, you can answer each query (test case) in O(1) by just returning (arr[n + 1] - 1) % p.

Just tried this and got accepted. Next time, please add problem link to your description, it is usually the case that you don´t think something is relevant and that part is the whole answer to the problem.

Comment: Time limit exceeds even by using the fast methods, maybe there is a different approach to this, please help me out if you get the solution

Comment: @sam which one did you try?

Comment: I tried using Wilson's theorem but still gave time limit exceeded. Could not implement the ones given in your comment, if you could provide the implementation it would be a great help. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There's a closed-form solution for the sum: `L = (N+1)!-1`

The sum follows this recurrent equation `L_N = N  + L_(n-1) + N*L_(n-1), L_0=0` which can be obtained by simply always choosing `X=L_(N-1)` and `Y=N` ( = the next number to add).

**Derivation:**

[image: derivation]

**EDIT:**

As you posted your final code, I'm posting my benchmark:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <chrono>

std::uint64_t
factorial(std::uint64_t n) {
    std::uint64_t x = 1;
    while (n > 1)
        x = (x * n--) % 1'000'000'007;
    return x;
}
int
main() {
    std::uint64_t n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::uint64_t numMicro = 0;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 1'000; ++i) {
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        volatile std::uint64_t res = factorial(n);
        auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        numMicro +=
            std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start)
                .count();
    }
    std::cout << "On average: " << numMicro / 1000.0 << "microseconds";
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `-O3`, `volatile` is there only to make sure that the compiler does not optimize the computation away.
Your solution is almost the same, way below the 1 second. Not sure what to optimize further.

Comment: For computing factorial I still need to compute it modulo 10^9+7 for every iteration as the numbers are large, which again exceeds the time limit. Any suggestions for this?

Comment: @Sam I highly doubt there's more compact solution but as 10^9+7 is prime, this question applies https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727962/fast-way-to-calculate-n-mod-m-where-m-is-prime .

Comment: @Sam Would you mind adding the final code to your question, because my naive factorial implementation for N=1e6 takes only ~4ms.

Comment: @Sam Posted my benchmark, I'm afraid I cannot do better than this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm should look like this:

sum <- 1
for index <- 2,n
    sum = (sum + index + sum * index) mod 1000000007
end for

Explanation: since + and * are commutative and associative, the order in which the items are handled is irrelevant, so you are doing a good job implementing this cycle, but you unnecessarily overcomplicate your cal function.

The other answers tell you to calculate ((n + 1)! - 1) mod modno, which is correct if we forget about the modulo part, but I doubt that calculating ((n + 1)! - 1) mod modno will yield the very same result as computing this in a step-by-step manner regardless of the value of n, because we have + and * in each step. If the other answerers are correct, then you can greatly optimize your algorithm. If not, then optimizing this is not as easy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem just says "`Choose two elements of the list, let's denote them by X and Y.`" and **doesn't say anything about the order that the elements need to be chosen**.

Therefore it could be rewritten as:

1. Split the list into one sub-list per CPU
2. Using SIMD; calculate `(X+1)*(Y+1)` for each pair in each CPU's
   sub-list and store the results in an new list as 64-bit integers so
   that you can avoid doing the expensive modulo operation
3. Using SIMD; calculate `(X*Y - 1) % 1000000007` for each pair in
   each CPU's new sub-list and store the results as 32-bit integers.
4. Repeat the previous 2 steps until you're left with one value from
   each CPU (and do the final `R = (R - 1) % 1000000007` if necessary to bring it back to 32-bit). Store these
   values in a list and terminate all threads except for one.
5. Using SIMD; calculate `(X+1)*(Y+1)` for each pair
6. Using SIMD; calculate `(X+*Y - 1) % 1000000007` for each pair
7. Repeat the previous 2 steps until you're left with one value

Comment: Can u provide an implementation of this? As mine seems to be giving some errors.